# Mode based on two condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Having a data set as below. Need to group the rows with product1:A and product2:B . If product1 is A and product2 is B, group based on that condition. then needs to fill the missing value using mode in that group.Need to fill the missing value of subgroup of a column:

[image: data]

Expected output

[image: output]

Code I tried:

```
data['Value'] = np.where((data['Product1'] =='A') & (data['Product2'] =='B'),merged['Value'].fillna(data['value'].mode()[0]),data['value'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
data = data\
    .set_index(['product1', 'product2'])\
    .fillna(
        data[data.product1.eq('A') & data.product2.eq('B')]\
            .groupby(['product1', 'product2'])\
            .agg(pd.Series.mode)\
            .to_dict()
    )\
    .reset_index()
```

This is actually a single line command but I've broken it into multiple lines for readability.

Result:

```py
    product1    product2    value
0   A           B           600.0
1   A           B           600.0
2   A           B           600.0
3   A           B           600.0
4   B           C           600.0
5   B           C           600.0
6   A           B           600.0
7   A           B           240.0
8   A           B           240.0
9   A           B           240.0
10  A           B           600.0
11  A           B           600.0
12  B           D           600.0
```

Or if you want to keep the type `int` use:

```py
data = data\
    .set_index(['product1', 'product2'])\
    .fillna(
        data[data.product1.eq('A') & data.product2.eq('B')]\
            .groupby(['product1', 'product2'])\
            .agg(pd.Series.mode)\
            .to_dict()
    )\
    .astype('int')\
    .reset_index()
```

Comment: I want to specifically take A from pduct 1 and B from pduct B.Can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want only `A, B` in te resulting table or do you want to replace the NaN only for `A, B`?

Comment: need to replace Nan only for A,B product

Comment: I edited the code with the requirement of only `A,B`